# PHP can't get the strings to match

Tags: php, string, loops, if-statement, comparison

I cannot seem to get the string that is in my variable to be detected by my loop.  In this code it is set to "BRONZE" and "I" and does not seem to do the comparison check correctly.  Any pointers on to why?

```
$teir = $league->data->summonerLeagues[0]->tier;
echo $teir;
$rank = $league->data->summonerLeagues[0]->requestorsRank;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rank);
echo '</pre>';

if($tier === "BRONZE")
{
${"s".$count."v"} += 0;
}
else if($teir == "SILVER")
{
${"s".$count."v"} += 5;
}
else if($teir == "GOLD")
{
${"s".$count."v"} += 10;
}
else if($teir == "PLATINUM")
{
${"s".$count."v"} += 15;
}
else 
{
${"s".$count."v"} += 20;
}

if($rank == "V")
{
${"s".$count."v"} += 1;
}
else if($rank == "IV")
{
    ${"s".$count."v"} += 2;
}
else if($rank == "III")
{
    ${"s".$count."v"} += 3;
}
else if($rank == "II")
{
    ${"s".$count."v"} += 4;
}
else
{
    ${"s".$count."v"} += 5;
}

echo '<pre>';
print(${"s".$count."v"});
echo '</pre>';
```

thanks for all your help!

Comment: There's a typo in the first comparison: `$tier` instead of `$teir`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You are using $tier to check for BRONZE and $teir for the other checks. The spellings are different.